# How to delete new objects from NSManagedObjectContext

Tags: objective-c, nsmanagedobject, restkit, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Ok, lets start with the code. I am looping through a returned array of dictionaries and creating (or updating) objects based on them. In this method I'm trying find or create a new entity. And then if the object is supposed to be deleted, I'd like to do so and not waste time updating it with the new information.

```
- (void)updateOrCreateObjectWith:(NSDictionary*)dictionary {
    RKManagedObjectStore *objectStore = ((MyAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).objectStore;

    id updateObject = (NSManagedObject*)[objectStore findOrCreateInstanceOfEntity:[resource entity] withPrimaryKeyAttribute:@"myID" andValue:[dictionary objectForKey:@"id"]];

    [updateObject setMyID:[dictionary objectForKey:@"id"]];

    // if marked for deletion, delete it now
    if ([[dictionary objectForKey:@"deleted_at"] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        if ([updateObject isNew]){
            NSError *error = nil;
            [objectStore.managedObjectContext save:&error];
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"error saving before delete: %@",error);
                return;
            }
//          [objectStore.managedObjectContext deleteObject:updateObject];
//          [objectStore.managedObjectCache delete:updateObject];  
        }
        else {
            [objectStore.managedObjectContext deleteObject:updateObject];            
        }
        return;
    }

    [updateObject updateWith:dictionary];
}
```

The part to be aware of is the deleted_at section with the (1) save section, (2) delete object from context, and (3) delete object from cache. I have tried a few combinations of those three but I don't get the desired results.

If I delete it from the cache (just #3):

- The objects get saved but they have no attributes.

If I delete it from the managed context (just #2) I get:

```
NSUnderlyingException=Cannot update object that was never inserted.
```

Since it was never inserted, I thought I'd save it and then delete it (#1 and #2), but then I get:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSObjectInaccessibleException', reason: 'CoreData could not fulfill a fault for '0xed27810 <x-coredata://4EE6AD5A-CC34-460A-A97A-0909454126A4/User/p166>''
```

So what is the proper way to remove a "new" object from NSMangedObjectContext?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to get the `RKManagedObjectStore` instance with `[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] objectStore]` (assuming you want the shared one, which it seems like you do since you're calling your app delegate).

Check for the `deleted_at` key before you ever create an NSManagedObject. This code assumes you're converting to type `Resource`, which is a subclass of `NSManagedObject`. It's untested but should give you an idea of what you should be doing.

```
- (void)updateOrCreateObjectWith:(NSDictionary*)dictionary {
RKManagedObjectStore *objectStore = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] objectStore];

    //get a reference to the object
    Resource *resource = [Resource findFirstByAttribute:@"myID" withValue:[dictionary objectForKey:@"id"]];

    //see if "deleted_at" exists in dictionary
    if ([[dictionary objectForKey:@"deleted_at"] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
    {
        //check to see if object exists in the context
        if(resource)
        {
            //if it exists, delete it
            [objectStore.managedObjectContext deleteObject:resource];
        }
    } else {
        //no "deleted at", so create the object
        if (!resource) {
            //resource is nil (it doesn't exist in the context), so we need to create it
            resource = [Resource object];
        }
        [resource updateWith:dictionary];
    }

    NSError *error = nil;
    [objectStore.managedObjectContext save:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"error saving before delete: %@",error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I guess I've been trying to put a square peg into a round hole. I've been using the single RKManagedObjectStore because I've been having issues when I try to build the relationships on my objects after the download. It just isn't finding things that I know are there. Any suggestions for that?

Comment: The shared RKManagedObjectStore is probably the same as the delegate's objectStore unless you didn't set the objectStore property on the sharedManager. As for your other question, it's difficult to answer without seeing some code; you should consider posting another question or asking in the google group or in the irc channel.

Answer (score 1):

You want to avoid creating managed objects unless necessary. The best strategy is to follow this pseudo code:

```
NSManagedObject *existingObject = ...; // fetch the object
if (existingObject) {
    if (deleted) {
        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject: existingObject];
    }
} else {
    if (!deleted) {
        // create the object, insert it into the MOC, set the object properties
    }
}
```